# Top integer homology of compact analytic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology, complex-manifolds

Let $V$ be a compact connected complex analytic subvariety (possibly singular) of a complex smooth manifold. Let $n$ denote its complex dimension.

**Is it true that $H_{2n}(V,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}$?**

A reference would be helpful.

Remark. I believe that the answer is positive, but have no idea how to prove it (I am not a specialist.)
Is it a difficult result?

Comment: For a smooth submanifold this is obvious (because a complex manifold is orientable). That is, the question is actually about the singular?

Comment: @AivazianArshak: Sure, the main case is of singular variety.

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed the case. In fact in the general case (possibily non compact) an irreducible complex analytic subvariety V has a fundamental class in Borel-Moore homology (in singular homology when $V$ is compact)

$$
[V]\in H_{2n}^{BM}(V;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.[V]
$$

see for example  "La classe d'homologie fondamentale d'un espace analytique" by Borel and Haefliger (BSMF, 1961).
Moreover if you consider a resolution of singularities
$$
\pi_*:\tilde{V}\rightarrow V
$$
Then you get an isomorphism
$$\pi_{*}:H^{BM}_{2n}(\tilde{V};\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{BM}_{2n}(V;\mathbb{Z}),\:\pi_*([\tilde{V}])=[V].$$

Comment: I read "connected" not "irreducible" in the question, so the answer seems obviously "no".  of course you may be assuming the word "variety" implies irreducible, but then why add "connected"?

Comment: @DavidC: Do you have a reference for the last statement (even if only in the case where $V$ is compact)?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : chapter 19 in Fulton's book "Intersection theory". Also section 3 of Totaro's paper "Torsion algebraic cycles and complex cobordism".